# xmlNode.SelectSingleNode always returns same value even though the node changes

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading in a bunch of XML files, transforming them and loading the data in to another system.

Previously I had done this using ThreadPool, however the provider of the files and therefore the structure has changed, so I'm  now trying Aysync-Await and getting an odd result.

As I process the files I get a list of the xmlNodes and loop over them

```
foreach (XmlNode currentVenue in venueNodes)
{
      Console.WriteLine(currentVenue.OuterXml);
      Console.WriteLine(currentVenue.SelectSingleNode(@"//venueName").InnerText);
}
```

however the second WriteLine always returns the result expected for the first node, example:

```
<venue venueID="xartrix" lastModified="2012-08-20 10:49:30"><venueName>Artrix</venueName></venue>
Artrix
<venue venueID="xbarins" lastModified="2013-04-29 11:39:07"><venueName>The Barber Institute Of Fine Arts, University Of Birmingham</venueName></venue>
Artrix
<venue venueID="xbirmus" lastModified="2012-11-13 16:41:13"><venueName>Birmingham Museum &amp; Art Gallery</venueName></venue>
Artrix
```

here is the complete code:

```
public async Task ProcessFiles()
{
    string[] filesToProcess = Directory.GetFiles(_filePath);
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (string currentFile in filesToProcess)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(()=>processFile(currentFile)));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

}

private async Task processFile(string currentFile)
{
    try
    {
         XmlDocument currentXmlFile = new XmlDocument();
         currentXmlFile.Load(currentFile);

         //select nodes for processing
         XmlNodeList venueNodes = currentXmlFile.SelectNodes(@"//venue");

         foreach (XmlNode currentVenue in venueNodes)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(currentVenue.InnerXml);
              Console.WriteLine(currentVenue.SelectSingleNode(@"//venueName").InnerText);                 
         }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
 }
```

Obviously I've missed something, but I cannot see what, can someone point it out please?

Comment: There is no reason to make `processFile()` `async`. You should get a warning about that. Also, processing files in parallel likely won't give you any performance improvement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SelectSingleNode` returns only a single node in document order from the document. @jbl is correct, `//venueName` starts from the document root. The `//` xpath operator is the "descendent selector" operator.

I work with XML and XPath often and this is a common mistake. You need to make sure that your context  node is correct when calling `SelectSingleNode`. So, like we just all said, using `//venueName` gets the first `<venueName />` node in document order starting from the root of the document.

In order to get the `<venueName />` node that is a child of the current node you're iterating over, you need to use the following code:

```
foreach (XmlNode currentVenue in venueNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(currentVenue.OuterXml);
    Console.WriteLine(currentVenue.SelectSingleNode(@".//venueName").InnerText); // The '.' means from the current node. Without it, searching starts from the document root, not currentVenue.
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I'm going to accept this answer as its more detailed and will hopefully help others in future.  I think that it is non-intuitive to have a method on a node object execute in the nodes parent document context.  it's like string[1].Contains("apple") searching the whole array instead of the string at index 1.  weird.

Comment: I agree with you that this is unexpected behavior on the part of `SelectSingleNode`. Like you, I at first thought that the method would be smart enough to set the context node to the node on which the method is being called. Not very intuitive at all. To give benefit of the doubt, maybe this has something to do with the Xpath spec....

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't `//venueName` search from the document root ?

I guess that, combined with `SelectSingleNode`, will always end-up on the same resulting  node (the first `venueName` node of the document)

You may try replacing `//venueName` with `venueName`

Comment: yes // does search from the root of the document, however in this instance the document is just one node that has been extracted

Comment: @Stuart It doesn't work like that. The `XmlNode` that you have is still linked to the whole document, you didn't “extract” it or anything like that.